# The Proof Of Basic Inequalities

Tags: proof-verification, geometric-inequalities

I am really curious about the *proofs* of the following inequalities. I know they are really easy problems but I couldn't prove them by myself.

1. $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb R^+$, with $a<b$ and $c<d$ implies $a \times c < b \times d$
2. $0 < a < b$  implies  $0 < a^n < b^n$
3. $a < b < 0$  implies  $a^{2n-1} < b^{2n-1} < 0$
4. $a < b < 0$  implies  $a^{2n} > b^{2n} > 0$
5. $0 < x < 1$  implies  $0 < x^n < x < 1$ ($n\in \mathbb Z^+$)

Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: Please show what you have thought about the problems and your progress on the problems

Comment: You'll have to be a little clearer in your notation.  For example when you write a^2n-1, it's not clear if you mean $a^{2n-1}$ or $a^{2n} - 1$.  You can fix this by putting in parentheses, e.g., a^(2n - 1) or a^(2n)-1.

Comment: This isn't a rigorous proof, but you can convince yourself of these inequalities by thinking about the graph.  For example, in 2) what does the function $f(x) = x^n$ look like?  You should see that it's increasing on $(0,\infty)$.  So that should convince you if $a < b$ then $a^{n} < b^{n}$.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting into into the logical foundations to define the reals.  One way of defining the real is that it is an [ordered Dedekin-complete field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number#Axiomatic_approach).  Take note especially of properties

- [A1] if $x ≥ y$ then $x + z ≥ y + z$
- [A2] if $x ≥ 0$ and $y ≥ 0$ then $x\cdot y ≥ 0$.

  1. - Let's see first that if $0 < a < b$ and $c \in \mathbb R^+$, then $a \cdot c < b \cdot c$.  Note that by [A1], $ b > a $ if only if $ b - a > 0$.  Since $c>0$, this means that by [A2], $(b-a)\cdot c > 0$.  By distributivity it means that $b \cdot c - a \cdot c > 0$, hence $b \cdot c > a \cdot c$
     - Using this, your proposition is easy:
       $$
       a \cdot c < b \cdot c < b \cdot d
       $$
  2. - Just use recursion.  If $0 < x < y$ and we assume $x^{n-1} < y^{n-1}$, then using the previous proposition 1., you obtain that $x^n < y^n$ (by having $a = x^{n-1}$, $b = y^{n-1}$, $c = x$ and $d = y$ in that proposition).
  3. - Observe that, $(-1)\cdot a = -a$ ($a$ times the opposite of the multiplication neutral $1$ equals the opposite of $a$) since
       $$a + (-1)\cdot a = a\cdot(1 + (-1)) = 0.$$
       But $-a$ is uniquely defined, which implies that $-a = (-1)\cdot a$.
     - Similarly observe that $(-1)\cdot(-1) = 1$ since by distributivity,
       $$(-1) + (-1)\cdot(-1) = (-1) \cdot (1 + (-1)) = (-1) \cdot 0 = 0.$$
       By the unicity of the opposite, this implies that $(-1)^2 = 1$.
     - Third observation, $x < y$ implies $-x > -y$.  Indeed $x < y$ if and only if $y - x > 0$.  But then, using the first observation that $-a = (-1)\cdot a$ and properties of fields,
       \begin{gather}
       (y-x)+(-(y-x)) > -(y-x),\\
       0 > -(y-x)\\
       0 > (-1)(y-x)\\
       0 > (-1)y - (-1)x\\
       (-1)x > (-1)y\\
       -x > -y
       \end{gather}
     - Final observation, by [A1], if $a<0$, then $-a>0$.  By the third observation this also means that $a < b < 0$ implies $0 > -b > -a$.
     - So by that last observation, we have $0 < -b < -a$.
       By proposition 2 this means $(-b)^{2n-1} < (-a)^{2n-1}$.  But by our first observation, $(-b)^{2n-1} = \big((-1)\cdot(b)\big)^{2n-1}$ and by commutativity, $(-b)^{2n-1} = (-1)^{2n-1} \cdot b^{2n-1}$.  By recursively applying our second observation, we conclude that $(-1)^{2b-1} = -1$ so that $(-b)^{2n-1} = - (b^{2n-1})$.
     - Putting it all together, we have $0 < -(b^{2n-1}) < -(a^{2n-1})$, which means that $b^{2n-1} > a^{2n-1} > 0$
  4. - It's simalar to 3.
  5. - I'll leave the details to you.  Try to show that $0 < x < 1$ iff $ \frac{1}{x} > 1$, that $0 < x < y$ iff $0 < \frac{1}{y} < \frac{1}{x}$, and using your first proposition that $x > 1$ implies $x^2 > x$.